# Put data from TextContext.Error.WriteLine() at beginning of output in NUnit default result writer

Tags: c#, .net, nunit, teamcity

I want to be able to display test category at beginning of error output generated by default result writer in NUnit. Idea is to be able to see this data clearly in TeamCity. Output information are very long and reading this data from end of `<output>` element is very difficult. Is there an option to do this without writing custom `IResultWriter`? Category implementation:

```
public class MyCategory : CategoryAttribute, ITestAction
{
    public string PropertyToShow { get; }

    public MyCategory(string value) : base(value)
    {
        PropertyToShow = value;
    }
    public ActionTargets Targets => ActionTargets.Test | ActionTargets.Suite;

    public void BeforeTest(ITest test) 
    { 
       TestContext.Error.WriteLine($"Property value: [{this.PropertyToShow}]");
    }

    public void AfterTest(ITest test)
    {
    }
}
```

I was trying also other options to put this property as part of test name but it makes everything even more messy.

Answer (score 0):

NUnit gives you two kinds of text output: normal output and immediate output.

Normal output includes output from Console.Out and TestContext.Out. It is always saved as part of the test result and is displayed at the end of the test. TestContext.WriteLine is short for TestContext.Out.WriteLine.

Immediate output, as the name suggests, is displayed immediately. This includes Console.Error, TestContext.Error and TestContext.Progress. TestContext.Progress is the normal output stream to use for non-error immediate output.

Comment: Thanks for answer. Unfortunately maybe I wrote not clear what I want to archive. I put some updates to original question. Please let me know if you have some idea.
So generally I want to be able to put this information at beginning of output for all failing tests.

Comment: Ah! I took "beginning of output" to mean beginning of the displayed console output, not beginning of the `<output>` element. `TestContext.Progress` output doesn't go to the XML at all, so it won't help you. OTOH, the order of text in the `<output>` element is the order in which it is produced.